# Why do I get a `Cross-Origin-Request-Blocked` in the console, but the route works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, web-development-server

I have a React app that connects to a database through flask.  The particular page I'm using is a "register user" type page.  When I enter the info and click register, in the console I get the red CORS errors triggered.  Yet, when I check the database, the data I submitted ends up there.  I thought if I have a CORS error, nothing is talking to each other.  On a high level, what is happening here?

Comment: have you checked the network tab in your browsers developer tools? See which request got flagged.

Comment: @CallumMorrisson I did!  It doesn't give me a status code, it does say `CORS Missing Allow Origin` though

Comment: So looking at it again it looks like I get a 500 code once then three other identical `CORS Missing Allow Origin` errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to add cors to your flask app as your react app is running on local server,  once you add cors your backend can work on any hosts .